# Google Cloud Kubernetes external autoscale

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I need to create a custom autoscaler in Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine.
I develope a software that write time series data to a custom metric in Google Cloud Monitoring and I want that Kubernetes autoscaler uses this data to manage the number of replicas.
I read a lot of documentation but I have a lot of doubts:

- Is mandatory to deploy the custom metrics stackdriver adapter? If yes, why?
- Which is the difference between "target total value" and "target average value" and how they work?
- I saw that is possible to create more than one metric, how autoscaler works with 2 or more metrics?